# OOP Ticket Price Program

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, while-loop

So this one is a bit lengthy. I'm trying to finish off a program where ticket price varies depending on purchase date. I need the Tester.Java to take the info from the objects, and output the proper price depending on the ticket type. I have already set a set of if statements in the Tester, but I am now at an impass on how to finish this program off. I will paste my code below.

Tester (contains the main method):

```
package tester;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester extends Ticket{
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner db = new Scanner(System.in);
    Ticket firstTicket = new Ticket();
    System.out.println("The first ticket: "+firstTicket.toString());
    int x = 0;
    while(x!=2){
        if(x==2){
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        }
        else{
           System.out.println("What type of ticket are you purchasing?");
           System.out.println("1.Walk Up");
           System.out.println("2.Advance");
           System.out.println("3.Student Advance");
           int t = db.nextInt();
           if(t==1){

           }
           if(t==2){

           }
           if(t==3){

           }

        }
     System.out.println("Do you need another ticket?");
     x= db.nextInt();            
    }        
  }   
}
```

Ticket (Super class):

```
package tester;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ticket {
    public int ticket;
    public double price;
  /**
   * holds default values for ticket number and price
   */
  public Ticket(){
    super();
    this.ticket=1;
    this.price=15.0;        
  }

  /**
   * Stores the values for ticket number and the price, based upon ticket type
   * @param ticket
   * @param price 
   */
  public Ticket(int ticket, double price){
    this.ticket=ticket;
    this.price=price;   
  }

  /**
   * returns the value of price
   * @return price
   */
  public double getPrice(){
    return price;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "Ticket #" + ticket + " Ticket price: $"+ price; 
  }
}
```

Walkup Ticket:

```
package tester;

/**
 *
 * @author dylan
 */
public class WalkupTicket extends Ticket{

/**
 * holds the price of a walkup ticket 50$
 */
public WalkupTicket(){
    this.price=50;
    ticket++;
  }
}
```

Advance Ticket:

```
package tester;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket {    
  /**
   * stores the values of an advance ticket, depending on how many days before
   * the event it is purchased
   */
  public AdvanceTicket(){
    Scanner db = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many days before the event are you purchasing your ticket?");
    int days = db.nextInt();
    // days before is 10 or less days
    if(days >= 10){
      price=30;
      ticket++;
    }
    // days before is more than 10
    else{
        this.price=40;
        ticket++;
    }
  }
}
```

Student Advance Ticket:

```
package tester;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentAdvanceTicket extends AdvanceTicket{
  /**
   * stores the values of an advance ticket, depending on how many days before
   * the event it is purchased, with student discount.
   */
  public StudentAdvanceTicket(){
   Scanner db = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many days before the event are you purchasing your ticket?");
    int days = db.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Are you a student?");
    System.out.println("1. Yes");
    System.out.println("2. No");
    int stud = db.nextInt();
    // days before is 10 or less days
    if(days >= 10 && stud == 1){
      price=15;
      ticket++;
    }
    // days before is more than 10
    if(days <= 10 && stud == 1){
        this.price=20;
        ticket++;
    } 
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm making a simple mistake, but I am new to OOP so I'm having bit of trouble with this.

Comment: It's not clear in your question what your error is and what result you are expecting from your program

Comment: Nice question, although a bit broad. And: details matter. Please have a look how I re-formatted your input to make it quicker/easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Are you supposed to be saving a total for all tickets bought or just the one ticket at a time total?

For walk-up tickets you don't have to do anything. Its a flat $50 total.

For Advance and StudentAdvance you would create a new object of that type and the way you have it the constructor will display the menu for how many days in advance and what not. You can then get the total from that.

As for the structure of your code it is not ideal. The object's constructor should not have all that code in it. They should have a ShowMenu function that will display the menu to the user and read their input. The constructor should be blank for the most part.

You also don't need three different ticket objects. One ticket object should be able to handle all this by itself. The ticket object can show the menu and handle the different prices based on user input. If you need to save a total or the different tickets you can have an array of ticket objects on the main method. You can then loop through that array to display or sum the tickets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this program need to have the three separate ticket objects. I would much rather do it with simple method calls but I was asked to do it with OOP instead.

Comment: Ok. Then you still want to pull the code out of the constructor and put them in a method. In the main ticket object you can make an abstract method called ShowMenu. Then in the classes that extend Ticket you will have to implement a method called ShowMenu in them. Each one can then show the menu that belongs to them.

Comment: @HarvP Nice answer, going into the oop details; have my vote for that. I put up another one, regarding various other aspects of this code; feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, but well, some thoughts on your input:

- **Names** matter. It is good that you made a first step and that you are using a specific package (instead of the default package); but `tester` says *nothing*. You could call it `dylan.tickets` for example: to make clear A) its your thing and B) it is about that ticket system
- It seems that you are serious about your work, thus: do not use a *static main* to drive testcases. Using JUnit and simple testcases is really easy. And beyond that: driving tests "manually" using a main is cumbersome and error prone. Unit tests are almost automatically automated.
- More importantly: tests that just **print** something are almost useless. If your code behaves unexpectedly, you might only notice when you carefully check that printed output. As said: use unit tests, and Junit assert calls to check expected versus actual results of method calls. Because then you will be told when you make changes that break functionality which was previously working.
- You **absolutely** avoid to ask for user input in so many different places. Meaning: the reasonable thing is that a class has a constructor or setter methods; and that all the arguments required to instantiate the new object are **given** to that object. If at all, your **main** uses a scanner and asks the user for input. But all your "business logic" objects do not require any "user interaction" at all. You see, you actually want to **start** the whole project *without* using a scanner. You want to **hardcode** things like `AdvancedTicket at = new AdvancedTicket(100);` - because now you can easily **code** all kinds of different objects; and start your program again and again. Your current solution requires you to enter all such data manually ... every time you re-start your program! So: no scanner usage in constructors. Never!
- Then: good OO is about **behavior**, not about state. Meaning: you dont use **public** fields to spread information. If at all, your fields should be **protected**; but even that is most often not a good idea. You want to isolate your classes from each other ...
- The core problem: it seems that nobody told you yet about [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You should *favor composition over inheritance*. Meaning: you dont just put `A extends B` everywhere. There is absolutely no reason that your Tester class **extends** Ticket. The tester is a Tester, not a ticket!

As said: that last point is the most important one. You are *careful* about making A a subclass of B; very often, it is more appropriate to maybe have A *own* a B object, but not to make A a B!